# Get all possible combinations of specific columns while retaining other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with FTA data. c1 to c91 denote different countries part of a FTA. I want to find all possible pairwise combinations of countries from c1 to c91, while keeping No, Base Treaty and entry type columns.

E.g of FTA data

```
No   Base_treaty   entry_type              c1           c2         c3
3     3            treaty                Algeria      Angola       Benin    
5     5            treaty                Albania      Bulgaria      NA  
6     6            treaty                Albania      Croatia       NA
```

Desired output:

```
No   Base_treaty   entry_type              ctry1       ctry2        
3     3            treaty                Algeria      Angola       
3     3            treaty                Algeria      Benin       
3     3            treaty                Benin        Angola       
5     5            treaty                Albania      Bulgaria      
5     5            treaty                Albania         NA      
5     5            treaty                Bulgaria        NA   
6     6            treaty                Albania      Croatia
```

What I have done so far:

`df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(cols), function(i) t(combn(output[i,4:6],2))))` where output is my FTA data. While this is able to give me the pairwise combinations across "c" columns, I am not able to copy over "No", "Base_treaty" and "entry_type" to each pair.

It only give me this:

```
        [,1]      [,2]           
[1,] "Algeria"  "Angola"
[2,] "Algeria"  "Benin"      
[3,]  "Benin"    "Angola"       
[4,] "Albania"  "Bulgaria"  
[5,] "Albania"    "NA"           
[6,] "Bulgaria"   "NA"
       .
       . 

       .
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. I'd put the column numbers as a function in `combn`, where we may `cbind` the steady columns with the combined. To find the number of the country columns we may use `grep` with a regular expression.

```
do.call(rbind, combn(grep("^c\\d+$", names(output)), 2, function(x) 
  cbind(output[1:3], setNames(output[x], paste0("c", 1:2))), simplify=F))
#   No Base_treaty entry_type       c1       c2
# 1  3           3     treaty  Algeria   Angola
# 2  5           5     treaty  Albania Bulgaria
# 3  6           6     treaty  Albania  Croatia
# 4  3           3     treaty  Algeria    Benin
# 5  5           5     treaty  Albania     <NA>
# 6  6           6     treaty  Albania     <NA>
# 7  3           3     treaty   Angola    Benin
# 8  5           5     treaty Bulgaria     <NA>
# 9  6           6     treaty  Croatia     <NA>
```

*Regex `"^c\\d+$"`:*

- `^` start of string
- `c` literally matching `"c"`
- `\\d+` one ore more digits
- `$` end of string

---

*Data:*

```
output <- structure(list(No = c(3L, 5L, 6L), Base_treaty = c(3L, 5L, 6L
), entry_type = c("treaty", "treaty", "treaty"), c1 = c("Algeria", 
"Albania", "Albania"), c2 = c("Angola", "Bulgaria", "Croatia"
), c3 = c("Benin", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Hello, @jay.sf thank you for your help! Just wondering what "^c\\d$" mean? Also my actual dataframe contains c1 all the way to c91. Do I need to change any part of the code to accommodate for this?

Comment: You're welcome @TanviJohri `"^c\\d+$"` is a [regular expression](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) that matches all strings starting with `"c"` and ending with digits, see edit.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much @jay.sf this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here an idea, that is close:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~No, ~Base_treaty, ~entry_type, ~c1, ~c2, ~c3
    , 3, 3, "treaty", "Algeria", "Angola", "Benin"    
    , 5, 5, "treaty", "Albania", "Bulgaria", NA  
    , 6, 6, "treaty", "Albania", "Croatia", NA)

df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("c")
                 , values_to = "country") %>%
    left_join(df %>%
                  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("c")
                               , values_to = "country")
              , by = c("No", "Base_treaty")) %>%
    select(starts_with("country")) %>%
    filter(country.x > country.y &
        country.x != country.y)

  country.x country.y
  <chr>     <chr>    
1 Angola    Algeria  
2 Benin     Algeria  
3 Benin     Angola   
4 Bulgaria  Albania  
5 Croatia   Albania
```

`pivot_longer()` puts the dataframe into a long format, having for each treaty all countries in one column. Then we left join the very same thing again and keep only the rows where the name of `country.x` comes first in the alphabet (and is not equal).